# determine position in xml

Tags: php, xml, xpath, position

I want to determine the position of the term "B&B Hotel Hamburg-Altona" in XML data.

The XML is as follows:

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<name>Hotel Grüner Berg</name>
</result>
<result>
<name>Hotel ABC</name>
</result>
<result>
<name>Hotel Lorem Ipsum</name>
</result>
<result>
<name>B&B Hotel Hamburg-Altona</name>
</result>
<result>
<name>Hotel Lorem Ipsum</name>
</result>
<result>
<name>Hotel Lorem Ipsum</name>
</result>
```

My php script:

```
$apiUmgebungUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=Hotel+in+Hamburg&radius=500&sensor=true&key=geheimerkey";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($apiUmgebungUrl, null, true);
echo $q = $xml->xpath('result/[contains(name,"B&B Hotel Hamburg-Altona")][position() <= 1]');
```

But i get the error:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid expression in
>   C:\xampp_18\htdocs\xmlposition.php on line 14
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed in
>   C:\xampp_18\htdocs\xmlposition.php on line 14

Answer (score 0):

The predicate (the condition in `[]`) should not be separated by `/` from the element name.

```
result[contains(name,"B&B Hotel Hamburg-Altona")][position() <= 1]
```

Also note that your XML is not correct: `&` should be represented as `&amp;`.

To get the position, count the number of preceding siblings:

```
count(result[contains(name,"B&B Hotel Hamburg-Altona")][position() <= 1]/preceding-sibling::*)
```

Comment: the xpath code do not deliver the number of position of Hotel Hafen Hamburg

    $apiUmgebungUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=Hotel+in+Hamburg&radius=500&sensor=true&key=secretkey";
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($apiUmgebungUrl, null, true);
    $q = $xml->xpath('result[contains(name,"Hotel Hafen Hamburg")][position() <= 1]');
    print_r($q['0']);

Comment: @susi87: `count(preceding-sibling::*)` gives the position.

Comment: but why is the array empty?

Comment: @susi87: If you do not use a context node, you should specify `//result` to make it search anywhere.

Comment: mh ok with this code i get allways 0 as result. `code echo $index = count( $xml->xpath('result[contains(name,"City Appartement Hotel")]/preceding-sibling::result')); code`

Comment: i uploaded the xml here. maybe it is helpfull http://de.sourcepod.com/dkdtrb22-19748

Comment: @susi87: As I mentioned in my previous comment, `count(//result[contains(name,"B&B Hotel Hamburg-Altona")][position() <= 1]/preceding-sibling::result)` works for me (returns 18).